# using nine-patch splashscreens in Multi-Device Hybrid applications

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Is there a way to use/define nine-patch splash screens in android platform?

I only managed to do it following the steps bellow:
**1.** change config.xml from 
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />`
to
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />`
**2.** clean/build or rebuild the project
**3.** go to folder bld\Debug\platforms\android\res and create a new folder named *drawable-nodpi*
**4.** add my *splash.9.png* file in this folder
**5.** build/deploy application

Subsequent clean or rebuilds will delete this directory. I can only use build or deploy and every time I need to clean or rebuild, I have to manually create the directory and copy the nine-patch png file.

Also, I don't think that the project honors the SplashScreen value entered in config.xml, as it always copies the files *screen-*-*.png* from *res\screens\android* to the build directories and not the *[SplashScreen]-*-*.png* (where [SplashScreen] is the value of preference named SplashScreen in config.xml and * are the supported resolutions and orientations).

Of course without this "bug" I wouldn't be able to use the above technique and have a nine-patch png for splashscreen in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place your image in this location and it will be copied there as part of the build:
`res\native\android\res\drawable-nodpi\splash.9.png`

Comment: Thank you, it does work. Is this mentioned in the documentation or FAQ? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Not currently. I'll follow up with the team to get this added.